# Java -DKRB5CCNAME not working

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I want to set kerberos ticket as java parameter using -DKRB5CCNAME during runtime

But it is not working in hadoop

I am following the below link,

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaha/rzahajgssknit.htm

```
set java_arguments=%JAVA_HEAP_MAX% -Dkrb5ccname=FILE:///ticketlocation %HADOOP_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSPATH% %CLASS% %hdfs-command-arguments%
call %JAVA% %java_arguments%
```

Some one help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with uppercase: KRB5CCNAME.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried already.

Answer (score 2):

Your link points to the **IBM JDK** which does not implement the Java extensions (cf. the **x** in `javax` classes) with the same syntax as **Sun/Oracle JDK** or **OpenJDK**.
Working with Sun/Oracle, I never heard of "KRB5CCNAME" as a Java system property.

The **generic way** to set a specific Kerberos ticket cache for all applications -- Java apps *(whatever the JDK you use)* and C++ apps and command-line tools like `kinit` -- is to define an **environment variable** named, no surprise, `KRB5CCNAME`.

- MIT Kerberos reference:
  https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/basic/ccache_def.html 
  *(the env. variable is mentioned at the very end)*
- An interesting read, not only for Hadoop users:
  https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html *(§6-7)*

Comment: Is there any way to set krb5ccname at run time within java application?

Comment: In general, yes, via the JAAS configuration (cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) -- with Hadoop, it should be possible, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jaas.html -- but then the Auth library manages its own JAAS config so maybe not all System params are honored; happy testing!